# Android KSoap2: how to get property name

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, getproperty

I am using KSoap2 for calling web-services for my Android app. I am using following code to call the web-service.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("PageSize", 20);
request.addProperty("PageIndex", currentPage);

SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
  aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
  SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

  Log.d("resBundle", String.valueOf(resBundle)); 

  int elementCount = resSoap.getPropertyCount();
  for(int i = 0;i<elementCount;i++){
    /////////////////////how to get the property name here////////////////
  }

}catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}
```

I am getting response from the web-services perfectly. The `String.valueOf` of response is below:

```
anyType{NewsID=2186; NewsSubject=Lil Wayne Shows Up to Heat Game With Mystery Chick & Drake; NewsDetail=Looks like Weezy found him a main chick! Lil Wayne showed off his mystery girl yet again, this time at the Miami Heat Eastern Conference Finals game. Wanye looked proud to be with his girl while he kept his arm around her for most of the game. Drake was also in attendance with Wanye and it looks like he was having a great time cheering on the Heat as they beat the Bulls in overtime. Chad Ochocinco was also spotted enjoying the game, but Evelyn was no where to be seen. Check out more pics from the Miami game:; NewsArtist=494; ModifiedDate=2011-05-26T12:03:04.567+01:00; CreateDate=26 May, 2011 12:03PM; ImageName=26052011120304.jpg; ImageAlt=anyType{}; ShortNewsDetail=Looks like Weezy found him a main chick! Lil Wayne showed off his mystery girl y; }
```

Now, I can easily get the value of property easily, but I also want to get the name property (e.g. NewsID, NewsSubject, NewsArtist, ModifiedDate). How do I get the name of the property?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where you loop trough your response you can get access to the PropertyInfo from the difrent property's. I used the following setup to get the names of the parameters and the values that go with them:

```
//Inside your for loop
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
resSoap.getPropertyInfo(i, pi);
Log.d(TAG, pi.name + " : " + resSoap.getProperty(i).toString());
```

This creates a PropertyInfo object, adds the information from the property in that object and then gives you access to all this information. And then prints it to your LogCat in the format off "propertyname : propertyvalue"

Answer (score 0):

//Inside your for loop

SoapObject dataObject ; // your SoapObject

PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();

dataObject.getPropertyInfo(i, property);

// this should give you the property name

String name= property.getName();

//happy coding