# Trying to extract SoapObject property name as string

Tags: java, android, soap

I am using trying to get the name of a SoapObject property into a string.
The SoapObject object:

```
anyType{ChassisReceiving=true;
JobOrderIssuing=true; 
MfgOrderReducing=true; 
PartsOrdering=true; 
PhysicalInventoryTaking=true; 
PurchaseOrderReceiving=true; 
SalesOrderReducing=true; }
```

which is expected. However, I am trying to just get the property name (i.e. ChassisReceiving, JobOrderIssuing, etc.).
I am trying to use: `String name = response.getProperty(i).toString();`
but `mod` comes back as `true`.
Full code:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) webService.getResponse();
                for (int i=0; i <= response.getPropertyCount()-1; i++) {
                    boolean modAllowed = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.getProperty(i).toString());
                    if (modAllowed) {
                        String mod = response.getProperty(i).toString();
                        switch (mod) {
                            case "ChassisReceiving":
                                mod = "Chassis Receiving";
                                break;
                            case "JobOrderIssuing":
                                mod = "Job Order Issuing";
                                break;
                            //add case for each property name
                        }
                        AddModule(response, mod);
                    }
                }
```

So far nothing I've tried results in `mod` coming back as anything other than `true`.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908752/8357735

Where you loop trough your response you can get access to the `PropertyInfo` from the different properties. I used the following setup to get the names of the parameters and the values that go with them:

```
//Inside your for loop
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
resSoap.getPropertyInfo(i, pi);
Log.d(TAG, pi.name + " : " + resSoap.getProperty(i).toString());
```

This creates a `PropertyInfo` object, adds the information from the property in that object and then gives you access to all this information. And then prints it to your LogCat in the following format.

```
<PropertyName> : <PropertyValue>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid. Got it working from this: [Android KSoap2: how to get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493762/android-ksoap2-how-to-get-property-name)

Essentially added: `PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();`
Then in the for loop: `response.getPropertyInfo(i, propertyInfo); String mod = propertyInfo.getName();`

Works as expected.