# How to iterate complex type of array in android

Tags: android, arrays, ksoap

how to iterate complex type of array in java

> anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{};
>   element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; };
>   }; }; };
>   diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{default=anyType{guesttranunkid=1;
>   guestunkid=1; phoneno=900000000; emailid=Piyush@mail.com; };
>   default=anyType{guesttranunkid=2; guestunkid=2; phoneno=992222222;
>   emailid=ja@gmail.com; }; default=anyType{guesttranunkid=3;
>   guestunkid=3; phoneno=9999999999; emailid=yuvi@gmail.com; };
>   default=anyType{guesttranunkid=4; guestunkid=4; phoneno=888888888;
>   emailid=sachin@gmail.com; }; default=anyType{guesttranunkid=5;
>   guestunkid=5; phoneno=111111111; emailid=DD@gmail.com; };
>   default=anyType{guesttranunkid=6; guestunkid=6; phoneno=3333333333;
>   emailid=DD@gmail.com; }; default=anyType{guesttranunkid=7;
>   guestunkid=7; phoneno=12121212; emailid=CSK@gmail.com; };
>   default=anyType{guesttranunkid=8; guestunkid=8; phoneno=1313131313;
>   emailid=CSK@gmail.com; }; default=anyType{guesttranunkid=9;
>   guestunkid=9; phoneno=1414141414; emailid=MI@gmail.com; };
>   default=anyType{guesttranunkid=10; guestunkid=10; phoneno=1515151;
>   emailid=Devid@gmail.com; }; default=anyType{guesttranunkid=11;
>   guestunkid=11; phoneno=16161616; emailid=Smith@gmail.com; }; }; }; }

Comment: you need to search for "Android how to parse KSOAP "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out this Tutorial for parsing such type of response

[`Web Service That Returns An Array of Objects With KSOAP`](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html)

[**Another way for parsing is using JSONObject and JSONArray**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270191/how-to-parse-this-web-service-response-in-android)

[**Manual Parsing of an Array of SoapObjects into an POJO array**](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Manual_Parsing_of_an_Array_of_into_an_POJO_array)

Comment: but i still emphasis to change the server response if he can, because parsing Json is very easy compare to Soap and Xml. with the help Gson, Jackson Json parsed in number of second and easy to understand. Still +1 with your answer :)

Comment: @hotveryspicy agree but we can't tell the user to change web-service as an answer, as an suggestion yes we can.

Comment: @hotveryspicy you may be right, but we can't make client to develope his existing WS in json from SOAP...rather we should learn SOAP parsing..

Comment: @hotveryspicy check my edited link, thats what you could have suggested :)