# String: How to insert double quotes around all occurrences of a character

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, insert

I have a string in which `:` occurs several times. I want each occurance of `:` to be surrounded by double quotes, like `":"` without truncating the data around it.

I have tried to use `String.replaceAll(":", "\":\"");` but it truncates the characters around `:`.

**How can I enclose all occurances of `:` by `"` without truncating the characters around `:`**?

---

EDIT:-

My String:-

```
{key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:{key4:value4,key5:value5,key6:{key7:{key8:value8}}},key9:value9}
```

More readable Form:-

```
{
    key1:value1,
    key2:value2,
    key3:{
        key4:value4,
        key5:value5,
        key6:{
            key7:{
                key8:value8
            }

        }

    },
    key9:value9
}
```

What I am doing:-

```
responseString = responseString.replaceAll(":", "\":");// Put " before each occurance of :

responseString = responseString.replace(":[^\\Q{\\E]", ":\""); // Put " after each occurence of : except the ones preceded by {
```

Output:-

```
{key1":"alue1,key2":"alue2,key3":{key4":"alue4,key5":"alue5,key6":{key7":{key8":"alue8}}},key9":"alue9}
```

Comment: `but it truncates the characters around : ` What does that mean? Any Example?

Comment: nothing wrong in calling replaceAll , are you calling it on String class , its not a static method of string class , call it on some other string

Comment: @TAsk `key1":value1` after doing `replaceAll(":",":/"")` becomes `key1":"alue1`

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Yeah I am using the particular String instance (my string) to call `replaceAll()` by dot notation like `myStrng.replaceAll(regex, replacement);`

Comment: `replaceAll(":",":/"")` is not the same as `replaceAll(":", "\":\"");`

Comment: you can try using replace method instead of replaceAll. That'll also works fine

Comment: [status-norepro] [could not reproduce.](http://ideone.com/Bg8eGc)

Comment: Whoever is downvoting the question and the answers, do you mind saying the reason? Because when you don't tell the reason, and we can't find out whatever the issue is, it only comes out that YOU have some issues!

Comment: not the DV'er but your original question does not reflect what it has evolved into.  Hence the problem could not be reproduced and the overall answers are just being stabs-in-the-dark

Comment: BTW, would it no be better to have your json correctly produced rather than trying to hack it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat You just hit a nerve. It was some response from a `web-service` (You can see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268924/weird-soap-response-is-it-json-how-to-parse-it))  which I have to parse and I am doing it this way (converting it to a format which can be converted to `JSONObject` and then retrieving values from the `JSONObject`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat By the way since you pointed out something related, may be you can suggest something about it. I had put a question on it yesterday: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268924/weird-soap-response-is-it-json-how-to-parse-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268924/weird-soap-response-is-it-json-how-to-parse-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method just works fine as `replaceAll` takes first argument as regExp second as replacement `String`.

For Example:

```
System.out.println("abc : pqr".replaceAll(":", "\":\""));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
abc ":" pqr
```

---

`replaceAll` doesn't change actual `String` it just returns the new replaced `String`

you need to assign it.

```
String str="key1\":value1";
str=str.replaceAll(":", "\":\"");
```

---

You can try this easy trick.

```
String str="{key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:{key4:value4,key5:value5,key6:{key7:{key8:value8}}},key9:value9}";
str=str.replaceAll("(:\\{)", "-");//Replace :{ to -
str=str.replaceAll("[:]", "\":\"");//replace : to ""
str=str.replaceAll("-", ":{");//again replace - to :{
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I did not downvote, I don't know who did and why, but I can atleast upvote your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not calling it on the right string object, but rather you are calling it on `String` class which will result in error as `replaceAll()` is not a static method of `String` class

This works just fine for me

```
String str1,str2;
str1 = "Hussain:Akhtar:Wahid:Ghouri";
str2 = str1.replaceAll(":", "\":\"");
System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
```

**Output**

> Hussain:Akhtar:Wahid:Ghouri
>
> Hussain":"Akhtar":"Wahid":"Ghouri

Comment: I do not know why somebody downvoted. Although could not get my question resolved but I probably could not make it clear while trying to make it simple, that's my bad. But I just edited my question and going to atleast upvote your answer.

Comment: @Zarah : thanx for the upvote , will review your question and my ans , but I still am waiting for downvoters response , can be something to learn for me

Comment: 1. It's possible to have a variable called `String`, so `String.replaceAll(...)` could in fact compile and run. 2. It's entirely possible `String.replaceAll(":", "\":\"");` was an example, and `String` wasn't actually the name of the variable. 3. The program evidently compiles and runs, otherwise OP would not be able to find out that characters are being deleted.

Comment: @user3580294 : 1 :its possible to declare a variable named 'String' but not expected thus i got to another approach , 2 : I too was saying  may she has called on the wrong object , 3 : I myself was telling it works absolutely fine without any error and OP

Comment: My point is that your guess is completely invalid. If OP tried to call `replaceAll()` as a static method the question would be *significantly* different as the code would never run, so OP would never find out that characters are being deleted.

Comment: @user3580294 : I gave both the scenario , anyways ,I wanted to know if I am missing any point , I got my ans , downvote is note the reason for me

Comment: You gave a wrong answer, and if you remove that what remains really should be a comment and not an answer. The point you're missing is that one of the scenarios you describe is entirely impossible. Bad answers get downvoted.

Comment: @user3580294 : downvote was hardly my point , the reason behind it was